# Get Property from Javascript Object Ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have a Rails and Ember app with two models Image and Project. Images belong to projects and projects have many images.

I am trying to return the first image from an given project to display on my project index page but can't seem to get past finding the image object.

Currently I have the following:

```
app/assets/javascripts/templates/projects.js.emblem

section#portfolio
  .container
    .row
      .col-xs-8.col-xs-offset-2
        .row
          each project in controller
            .col-xs-12.col-sm-6
              p = project.firstImage
              link-to 'project' project
                h4.text-center.text-uppercase
                  = project.client
              h5.text-center
                em
                  = project.tags 


app/assets/javascripts/models/project.js

App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  client: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  start_date: DS.attr('string'),
  end_date: DS.attr('string'),

  images: DS.hasMany('image'),

  projectDuration: function() {
    return this.get('start_date') + ' - ' + this.get('end_date')
  }.property('start_date', 'end_date'),

  firstImage: function() {
    var projectImages = this.get('images');
    var projectImage = projectImages.get('firstObject');
    return projectImage;
  }.property('images')

});
```

Images have properties of id, project_image (which is a string of the URL) and project_id.

The current setup will show `<App.Image:ember323:6>` in the view which is the correct object but I can't seem to get the project_image string from the object?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

---

Sorry forgot to share my image model

```
app/assets/javascripts/models/image.js
App.Image = DS.Model.extend({
  _project_image: DS.attr('string'),
  _project_id: DS.attr('number'),


  project: DS.belongsTo('project')
});
```

Comment: In Handlebars.js you would do something like - `<img {{bind-attr src=project.firstImage.SRC_PROPERTY_OF_IMAGE_MODEL}}/>` - you didn't share code for Image model.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, by looking at my own image model I can see that I am adding and _ to all properties when passing it from my rails API. This was to make the JSON data format correctly when reaching Ember but I was forgetting to add the underscore to the property in the view. Thanks for helping me notice :)